# How many passwords can be made using letters and one number?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

If I am making a ten character long password, consisting of uppercase and lowercase letters, and at least one number, how many possibilities are there?
When I calculated it I got:
   $(10*10)(62^9)=1.3537087e+18$

However, this seems awfully high and it doesn't seem like my equation takes into account position properly.

Answer (score 1):

There are 52 lowercase and uppercase letters and 10 digits, for a total of 62 characters. Assuming characters can be repeated, that is a total of $62^{10}$ passwords. However, if you are going to require at least one number, you have to then subtract all of the combinations that include no numbers, of which there are $52^{10}$, so the correct number of passwords is $62^{10} - 52^{10}$.

Comment: This is a good, constructive answer.  What kind of person would down vote it and not have the cajones to post a comment?  He needs to take his trilby off and go play outside.